# How to remove special characters in post title

Tags: posts, characters

Please guys

I need help on how to remove special characters in POST TITLE -

Certain SYMBOLS LIKE < > { }

Please Note: I am a beginner coder, kindly make the solution very simple for me to understand

Comment: What exactly do you mean by special characters - emojis, accents / other diacritics, certain symbols, anything that's not A-Z ?

Comment: @Rup Yes, certain symbols like < > { }

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordPress function [wp_strip_all_tags()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $string ),
  );
```

Or you can also use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) :

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function:

```
sanitize_title( string $title, string $fallback_title = '', string $context = 'save' );
```

More info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/

Comment: That's for generating slugs though, not page titles. As one of the comments says "Despite the name of this function, the returned value is intended to be suitable for use in a URL, not as a human-readable title."

Comment: you can use filter sanitize_title & do preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $title);

Comment: I am a beginner coder,  Please, make it more explanatory for me. Where should I add this snippet code?